# Where can one find the midrash Tadsha?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

I saw something intresting brought from the midrash tadsha. I want to know where can I find this midrash. Online sources or/and where to buy online would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can find it on Hebrewbooks [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/33677) or another version on Otzar HaHochma [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=200088).

Comment: Beat me by 38 seconds. Although I linked to the specific piece ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Midrash Tadshe can be found in Hebrewbooks

I believe the particular teaching cited in your screenshot is [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21342&st=&pgnum=44).